# Как анимировать радиальный градиент с помощью CSS?

Tags: css, html5, svg, css-animation, градиент

Я пытаюсь создать эффект анимации блеска с радиальным градиентом для блока div, но я не уверен, что мой способ, - лучший способ сделать это.

Я не нашел других решений для достижения того, чего я хочу получить. 
Примеры, которые я нашел, - это просто эффекты блеска, которые выглядят как наложение.

Большинство примеров, которые я нашел, выглядит так:   http://jsfiddle.net/nqQc7/512/.

Ниже то, что у меня пока получилось:

```css
#shine-div {
  height: 30vh;
  width: 60vw;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  border-radius: 10px;
  /*background: radial-gradient(ellipse farthest-corner at right top, #FFFFFF 0%, #ffb3ff 8%, #ff33ff 25%, #800080 62.5%, #b300b3 100%);*/
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  animation: colorChange 5s infinite;
}

@keyframes colorChange {
  0% {
    background: radial-gradient(ellipse farthest-corner at left top, #FFFFFF 0%, #ffb3ff 8%, #ff33ff 25%, #800080 62.5%, #b300b3 100%)
  }
  50% {
    background: radial-gradient(ellipse farthest-corner at top, #FFFFFF 0%, #ffb3ff 8%, #ff33ff 25%, #800080 62.5%, #b300b3 100%)
  }
  100% {
    background: radial-gradient(ellipse farthest-corner at right top, #FFFFFF 0%, #ffb3ff 8%, #ff33ff 25%, #800080 62.5%, #b300b3 100%)
  }
  /*0% { transform: translateY(-20vh) translateX(-7vw) ; opacity: 0;  }*/
  /*10% { transform: translateY(-20vh) translateX(-7vw) ; opacity: 1;  }*/
  /*40% { transform: translateY(-20vh) translateX(17vw) ; opacity: 1; }*/
  /*50% { transform: translateY(-20vh) translateX(17vw) ; opacity: 0; }*/
  /*60% { transform: translateY(-20vh) translateX(17vw) ; opacity: 1; }*/
  /*90% { transform: translateY(-20vh) translateX(-7vw) ; opacity: 1; }*/
  /*100% { transform: translateY(-20vh) translateX(-7vw) ; opacity: 0; }*/
}
```

```html
<div id="shine-div">
  Shine
</div>
```

Возможно ли и как,  заставить белый блеск сверху плавно переходить слева направо?

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/57218443/7394871

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Решение SVG

Все фильтры, градиенты, маски, клипы пришли в CSS из SVG. Поэтому необходимо добавить решение c SVG градиентами.

Всё в принципе повторю из css решения, те же цвета в `stop-color`, те же проценты в `stop offset`

**Горизонтальное перемещение градиента**

Анимация достигается изменением значения параметра `fx` радиального градиента, отвечающего за горизонтальную координату центра градиента.

*Запуск анимации - клик по прямоугольнику*

```html
<div id="shine-div">
  
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="400"  height="100" viewBox="0 0 400 100">
   <defs>
   <radialGradient id="radGrad"  fx="0%" fy="5%" r="200%"
           >
     <stop offset="0%" stop-color ="#FFFFFF" />
      <stop offset="4%" stop-color ="#ffb3ff" />
       <stop offset="12.25%" stop-color ="#ff33ff" />
        <stop offset="31.25%" stop-color ="#800080" />
         <stop offset="50%" stop-color ="#b300b3" /> 
         
   </radialGradient>
   </defs> 
    <g id="gr1" > 
   <rect id="rect1" fill="url(#radGrad)" x="5%" y="5%" width="95%" height="95%" rx="10%"  /> 
      <text x="50%" y="60%" font-size="28px"  text-anchor="middle" font-weight="bold" font-family="sans-serif" fill="#FFDD00" > Sun shine </text>
    </g>  
    <animate xlink:href="#radGrad"
      attributeName="fx"
      dur="2s"begin="gr1.click"
      values="0%;50%;50%;100%;0%"
      repeatCount="1"
      restart="whenNotActive" />
  </svg>
</div>
```

Атрибут `keyTimes` обеспечивает неравномерность движения, количество значений должно равняться количеству значений в атрибуте `values`  Подробнее [здесь](https://svg-art.ru/?p=1674).

```
  values="0%;50%;50%;100%;0%"
keyTimes="0;0.1;0.5;0.9;1"
```

**Вертикальная анимация градиента**

В этом случае анимируется `fy`

```html
<div id="shine-div">
  
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="400"  height="100" viewBox="0 0 400 100">
   <defs>
   <radialGradient id="radGrad"  fx="48%" fy="0%" r="200%"
           >
     <stop offset="0%" stop-color ="#FFFFFF" />
      <stop offset="3%" stop-color ="#ffb3ff" />
      <stop offset="12.25%" stop-color ="#ff33ff" />
      <stop offset="31.25%" stop-color ="#800080" />
        <stop offset="50%" stop-color ="#b300b3" /> 
         
   </radialGradient>
   </defs> 
    <g id="gr1" > 
   <rect id="rect1" fill="url(#radGrad)" x="5%" y="5%" width="95%" height="95%" rx="10%"  /> 
      <text x="50%" y="60%" font-size="28px"  text-anchor="middle" font-weight="bold" font-family="sans-serif" fill="#FFDD00" > Sun shine </text>
    </g>  
    <animate xlink:href="#radGrad"
      attributeName="fy"
      dur="2s"begin="gr1.click"
      values="0%;50%;50%;100%;50%;50%;0%"
      repeatCount="1"
      restart="whenNotActive" />
  </svg>
</div>
```

**Анимация по диагонали**

Анимируются одновременно оба параметра `fx`, `fy`

```html
<div id="shine-div">
  
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="400"  height="100" viewBox="0 0 400 100">
   <defs>
   <radialGradient id="radGrad"  fx="0%" fy="0%" r="200%">
     <stop offset="0%" stop-color ="#FFFFFF" />
      <stop offset="3%" stop-color ="#ffb3ff" />
      <stop offset="12.25%" stop-color ="#ff33ff" />
      <stop offset="31.25%" stop-color ="#800080" />
      <stop offset="50%" stop-color ="#b300b3" /> 
         
   </radialGradient>
   </defs> 
    <g id="gr1" > 
   <rect id="rect1" fill="url(#radGrad)" x="5%" y="5%" width="95%" height="95%" rx="10%"  /> 
      <text x="50%" y="60%" font-size="28px"  text-anchor="middle" font-weight="bold" font-family="sans-serif" fill="#FFDD00" > Sun shine </text>
    </g>  
    <animate xlink:href="#radGrad"
      attributeName="fy"
      dur="2s"begin="gr1.click"
      values="0%;50%;50%;100%;50%;50%;0%"
      repeatCount="1"
      restart="whenNotActive" />
         <animate xlink:href="#radGrad"
      attributeName="fx"
      dur="2s"begin="gr1.click"
      values="0%;50%;50%;100%;50%;50%;0%"
       repeatCount="1"
      restart="whenNotActive" />
  </svg>
</div>
```

**Анимация по наведению курсора**

Условие запуска анимации:   `begin="rect1.mouseover"`

```html
<style>
 
</style>
<div id="shine-div">
  
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="400"  height="100" viewBox="0 0 400 100">
   <defs>
   <radialGradient id="radGrad"  fx="0%" fy="5%" r="200%"
           >
     <stop offset="0%" stop-color ="#FFFFFF" />
      <stop offset="4%" stop-color ="#ffb3ff" />
      <stop offset="12.25%" stop-color ="#ff33ff" />
      <stop offset="31.25%" stop-color ="#800080" />
      <stop offset="50%" stop-color ="#b300b3" /> 
         
   </radialGradient>
   </defs> 
    <g id="gr1" > 
   <rect id="rect1" fill="url(#radGrad)" x="5%" y="5%" width="95%" height="95%" rx="10%"  /> 
      <text x="50%" y="60%" font-size="28px"  text-anchor="middle" font-weight="bold" font-family="sans-serif" fill="#FFDD00" > Sun shine </text>
    </g>  
    <animate xlink:href="#radGrad"
      attributeName="fx"
      dur="1s"
      begin="rect1.mouseover"
       values="0%;100%;0%"
       repeatCount="1"
     fill="freeze"
       />
  </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: я конечно плюсик поставил но на css работает лучше

Comment: Саша там плавность а в SVG её нету - дёргается

Comment: ни чего страшного в общем - это не критично , на другую тему есть вопрос у меня

Comment: @MaximLensky Добавлена плавность хода

Answer (score 8):

Вы можете сделать градиент по-разному и анимировать его позицию. Хитрость состоит в том, чтобы удвоить размер градиента и сделать так, чтобы значение `stop-color` составляло половину их фактических значений, чтобы сохранить тот же визуальный градиент, а затем анимировать его слева направо.

- Он не будет выглядеть точно так же, как градиент, который вы
  определили в анимации из-за вычисления дальнего угла

  ```css
  #shine-div {
    height: 30vh;
    width: 60vw;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background: radial-gradient(farthest-corner at top, #FFFFFF 0%, #ffb3ff 4%, #ff33ff 12.25%, #800080 31.25%, #b300b3 50%) top right/200% 200%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    animation: colorChange 5s infinite alternate;
  }

  @keyframes colorChange {
    to {
      background-position:top left;
    }
  }
  ```

  ```html
  <div id="shine-div">
    Shine
  </div>
  ```
- Чтобы приблизиться к вашему примеру с градиентами, вы также можете
  анимировать размер:

  ```css
  #shine-div {
    height: 30vh;
    width: 60vw;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background: radial-gradient(farthest-corner at top, #FFFFFF 0%, #ffb3ff 4%, #ff33ff 12.25%, #800080 31.25%, #b300b3 50%) top right/400% 200%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    animation: colorChange 5s infinite alternate linear;
  }

  @keyframes colorChange {
    from {
      background-position:top 0 left 33%;
      background-size:400% 200%;
    
    }
    50% {
      background-position:top center;
      background-size:200% 200%;
    }
    to {
      background-position:top 0 right 33%;
      background-size:400% 200%;
    }
  }
  ```

  ```html
  <div id="shine-div">
    Shine
  </div>
  ```
- Вы также можете сделать ту же анимацию с учетом псевдоэлемента и
  `transform`, чтобы иметь лучшую производительность:

  ```css
  #shine-div {
    height: 30vh;
    width: 60vw;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    border-radius: 10px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    overflow:hidden;
    position:relative;
    z-index:0;
  }
  #shine-div:before {
    content:"";
    position:absolute;
    z-index:-1;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width:400%;
    height:200%;
    background: radial-gradient(farthest-corner at top, #FFFFFF 0%, #ffb3ff 4%, #ff33ff 12.25%, #800080 31.25%, #b300b3 50%);
    animation: colorChange 5s infinite alternate linear;
  }

  @keyframes colorChange {
    from {
      transform:translateX(-50%);
    }
    50% {
      transform:scaleX(0.75) translateX(-50%)
    }
    to {
      transform:translateX(-25%);
    }
   }
  ```

  ```html
  <div id="shine-div">
    Shine
  </div>
  ```

Comment: плюсанул как обычно

Comment: Присоединился к комментатору выше.